# Difference between mpg123 and mpg123-alsa

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

On my Ubuntu machine I have both `mpg123` and `mpg-alsa` in `/usr/bin` (though former is linked to `/etc/alternatives/mpg123`).

The documentation for both just says that they read files and URLs and play them on an audio device.

What is the difference? (Note: I have audio problems (noise, stutter) and want to know whether one or both can help to track down my problem (sound card/cpu/pulseaudio/alsa/player/...).)

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: Version Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

If you examined the files relevent to mpg123 in /usr/bin you would see

```
0   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 2013-12-21 21:52 /usr/bin/mpg123 -> /etc/alternatives/mpg123*
4   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     50 2013-12-20 06:41 /usr/bin/mpg123-alsa*
20  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18236 2013-12-20 06:41 /usr/bin/mpg123-id3dump*
4   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     50 2013-12-20 06:41 /usr/bin/mpg123-jack*
4   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     49 2013-12-20 06:41 /usr/bin/mpg123-nas*
4   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     52 2013-12-20 06:41 /usr/bin/mpg123-openal*
4   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     49 2013-12-20 06:41 /usr/bin/mpg123-oss*
4   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     55 2013-12-20 06:41 /usr/bin/mpg123-portaudio*
12  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   9912 2013-12-20 06:41 /usr/bin/mpg123-strip*
132 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 132764 2013-12-20 06:41 /usr/bin/mpg123.bin*`
```

and you should take notice that the "sound-system-specific" versions of mpg123 are very small.

Examining mpg123-alsa would show you that

```
 $> file /usr/bin/mpg123-alsa

 /usr/bin/mpg123-alsa: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable

 $> cat /usr/bin/mpg123-alsa 

 #!/bin/sh

 exec /usr/bin/mpg123.bin -o alsa "$@"
```

[NB Do not blindly cat any file, particularly in /bin,/usr/bin,/lib,/usr/lib etc because if the file is binary, it will mess up your terminal and also usually result in much beeping of the PC loudspeaker if that is enabled.]

it is just a simple "convenience" shell script to call the actual mpg123 binary with output defaulting to the ALSA interface.

Please disregard the answer below which states

"ALSA is not providing support to mpg123"

because the poster has misunderstood (actually got the information backwards) what the page at Alsa-Project is saying.  [Note that the Alsa-Project page can be very useful but it is not kept up to date and some information there is long past its sell-by-date.]  ALSA does not support any particular application but it is the applications which provide support to the user for a particular sound system interface (be it PulseAudio, ALSA, OSS, esound etc).  What that web page is stating is that the old deprecated ALSA 0.5 version can no longer be used with mpg123, but the page has not been updated to say that the latest and greatest mpg123 does work with the current ALSA version.

So to answer your question, output from mpg123 manually set to output to ALSA (with -o command line flag and the parameter alsa) is totally the same as just using mpg123-alsa

As to your problem with clicking/stuttering PulseAudio you really a separate question on this and its cause can come from numerous places.

The first most usual suspect is the resample method if the clicking/stuttering occurs with a sound file being played back which has to be resampled to match the hardware sampling rate (usually now 48.0 kHz or even 96.0 kHz) which is different from the audio sound file sample rate (usually but not always 44.1 kHz).

If the resample method is chosen to give the absolute best quality, it may put too much strain on the available PC real time resources, so going for a lower quality method in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

```
resample-method                         = speex-float-1
```

and doing a check on sound output for no apparent clicking/stuttering would then provide a diagnosis.  If that is the issue than gradually increasing the resample-method quality (and load on system) to the level one or possibly tow just before clicking/stuttering starts by trial and error, would then be the solution.

For further information about PulseAudio configuration, particularly in relation to resample-method, please take a look at

[Freedesktop - PulseAudio Documentation User Audiophile](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Audiophile/)

[Overclock - Best sound and configure PulseAudio](http://www.overclock.net/a/how-to-get-the-best-sound-with-and-properly-configure-pulseaudio)

[ArchWiki - PulseAudio Configuration](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Configuration)

and of course, the original DEFINITIVE configuration guide

[Freedesktop - PulseAudio Perfect Setup](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/PerfectSetup/)

And for the record, to dispel the fallacy that many Ubuntu users believe and disseminate, it is not a case of using PulseAudio **or** ALSA -- if you use PulseAudio which sits on top of ALSA, then you are using ALSA, just not directly.

Also the default configuration on Ubuntu for ALSA, set in /usr/share/alsa/pulse-alsa.conf is for thje sound sent to the default ALSA ctl and pcm to be sent not to the default ALSA hardware device hw:0 but to PulseAudio, so one is in fact be sending to PulseAudio if using ALSA default without specifying the hardware device hw:0 or if resampling is necessary plughw:0

Answer (score -1):

**ALSA(Advanced Linux Sound Architecture)** is `sound driver` that provides audio and MIDI functionality to the Linux operating system. previously it was supporting  `mpg123` in older version 0.5.0 of ALSA. now ALSA is not providing support to `mpg123` and announced it as deprecated. more info [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Applications)

**mpg123** is a  audio player and  decoder library

Comment: That info is easy to find. But my question is why is there `mpg123` *and* `mpg-alsa`? There surely is a good reason why there are two and there surely is a difference.